# Organic Chemistry Inductive and Basic effects

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Do all basic groups show +I effect?

Or do they simply exhibit an electron donating tendency which has nothing to do with Inductive effects?

I can't decide if the electronegativity and basicity are completely decoupled phenomena. Does one have an effect on the other?

Or do I always have to consider them separately.

(note: I'm talking about lewis bases not just ones with -OH groups)

Comment: The basicity is determined by the amount of -OH ions present in solution, pka values are associated with electronegativit y and net charge.

Comment: Can you give an example of these "basic" groups that you are talking about? Functional groups or substituents aren't usually classified as Lewis basic.

Comment: @orthocresol really? I heard amines being classified as Lewis bases often enough … or thioethers …

Comment: @OP: $\ce{NH2}$ is a basic group but shows a $-\mathrm{I}$ effect. These two have nothing to do with each other. Electronegativity and basicity are also two only distantly related concepts.

Comment: @Jan well, it's quite a trivial argument but I never hear the functional group itself being called a Lewis base, it's usually the molecule being called a Lewis base. I imagine OP was referring to -NH2, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: Btw, organic compounds with -OH groups aren't Lewis basic!! They do *not* generate $\ce{OH-}$ in solution. In fact, phenols and alcohols are weakly acidic.

Comment: @orthocresol They can be protonated, so they can act as basic groups, even ring itself can be.

Comment: @Mithoron oh dear, I'm being stupid (again)... I should have just said they don't generate $\ce{OH-}$ in solution. Arrhenius acidity/basicity. They can most certainly act as Lewis bases.

Comment: @orthocresol I just wanted to know if I have to take electronegativity into account while comparing while comparing different lewis bases. And if I have to, how much of an effect electronegativity has on basicity. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Don't worry, it's my bad. My brain hasn't really been working recently... Anyway, electronegativity determines the +I/-I effects. As Jan said, basicity often has very little to do with it. Inductive effects are about how strongly the group donates/withdraws electrons from adjacent atoms (usually carbons) in the same molecule, whereas (Lewis) basicity is a measure of how strongly the group donates electrons to an external Lewis acid, such as $\ce{H+}$. Superficially they may seem similar, but the electrons that play a role in these two phenomena are different.

Comment: @orthocresol Yeah that makes sense. Thank you! :)
(and cool name by the way)

Answer (score -2):

In **Inductive effect** due to the EN difference between the adjacent atom or group, polarisation of sigma bond occurs, which causes a partial + and -  charge on them. It is a permanent effect, which is effective upto 4-6$C$ only.

+I: polarisation occurs **away** from the atom or group, i.e., the adjacent group attached will act as electron pusher or donor or will have EN less than the carbon. 
Example

$\ce{CH3-(C=O)OH }$,   $\ce{-CH3}$ will acquire a partial + charge and $\ce{-(C=O)OH }$ will acquire partial - charge.

-I: polarisation occurs **towards** from the atom or group, i.e., the adjacent group attached will act as electron puller or acceptor or will have EN more than the carbon.

Example 
 $\ce{CH3-CH2-NO2}$,  $\ce{-CH2-CH3}$ will have partial + charge and  $\ce{-NO2}$ will have partial -  charge.

As far as **Lewis base** is concerned its generally an *electron pair donor*,  which makes it electron pucher **most of the time** , so, such lewis base would show +I effect.